# How to make an animated circle getting smaller and darker

Tags: animate, circles

How do I make a animated filled circle that gets smaller and changes its color? I'm using the beamer class.

Comment: In order to ensure no marmots are harmed in producing an answer I think the **cover page** of this explanation says it perfectly \usepackage[dynamic opacity]{caution} http://optical-astronomy.education/onewebmedia/var2.pdf

Comment: Please provide us with an MWE that shows what you have tried. Judging from your previous question, there is a chance you want to embed it into a beamer document. If so, this changes the story because beamer comes with `\animate`, and it definitely allows you to animate the color of a circle, the radius or both.

Comment: @marmot yeah sorry that i did not provide any MWE becuase I did not know how to get even started. But thank you for showing me how to animate a circle really helpful!

Comment: Changing the question in after having accepted an answer is IMHO not a good style. Anyone considering to write an answer here should be warned that this may happen to your answer as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a do it for me question.

Comment: Close voters: this question is less than a day old

Comment: OP please add more details of what you wish to achieve preferably with a small document showing the context.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I opened  a new question to give a little MWE (all I was able to do and im still working on it). [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479754/how-to-make-an-animated-circle-that-changes-the-color). There is a video which shows what  I want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want beamer again.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcount\mypar

\begin{document}
\transduration{2}
\animate<2-22>
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]{Frame title}
\animatevalue<2-21>{\mypar}{0}{20}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myfrac}{50+50*cos(\mypar*18)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{3+cos(\mypar*18)}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-4.2,-4.2) rectangle (4.2,4.2);
 \fill[yellow!\myfrac!red] circle[radius=\myradius];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to show the animation in a presentation, view it with acroread in full screen mode.

Comment: thanks again. Now i made a "MWE" in order to get this control panel.

Comment: Of course did not think about that. Won't happen again!