# How to make an animated Circle that changes its size and color

Tags: animate

So I just started using Latex. I'm trying to make a circle, that decreases in size and increases again. This is my approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate} %dont know if it's necessary
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\centering
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{10}
\multiframe{5}{irad=5+-1} %is this the correct way to decrease the number?
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \filldraw[fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (irad*1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So this is what i get. I do not know why the control panel so wierd positioned. Also i want to change its color. [This video](https://youtu.be/GKoPbk_A7Kk?t=391) shows how it should look like in the end in order to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things to adjust in your code.

Firstly, the variable is specified in `\multiframe` as `irad=9+-1`.  This is the correct to specify an integer variable starting at `9` and decreasing by `1` each time.  (It is an integer since the variable name starts with `i`.)  However, having it set-up this way you then have to use as `\ired`, not just `ired`, in the subsequent `tikzpicture`, i.e. you need to add a backslash before the name when you use, but the backslash should not be there when you define it.

If you do this, you will notice is that your circle is far too large to fit in the frame, so you should scale by say `.1cm` instead of `1cm`.

Secondly, the animate package (which you do indeed need to load) rescales your images to the size of the first one.  This is not desirable in your case.  One way around is provide a fixed bounding box for each image, e.g. via `\useboundingbox` in `tikz`.  You should make this box large enough to contain the biggest image.  In the code below, I have used

```
\useasboundingbox (-1.1cm,-1.1cm) rectangle (1.1cm,1.1cm);
```

which makes a bounding box with lower left corner `(-1.1cm,-1.1cm)` and upper right corner at `(1.1cm,1.1cm)`.

Thirdly, for the position on the page, I would suggest you just place every thing inside a `center` environment.  Alternatively, you could make the bounding box above, wider than the set of controls.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls]{1}
      \multiframe{9}{irad=9+-1}
      {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-1.1cm,-1.1cm) rectangle (1.1cm,1.1cm);
        \filldraw[fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (\irad*.1cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \end{animateinline}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Simba : The loop variable can also be a dimension: `drad=.9cm+-.1cm`